# Get current route name on handlebar template in Ember.js 2

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I needed to know the current route name so I can show or hide a global component that is created on my `application.hbs`.

This component should be hidden in just one route template, so this looks like the easier solution to me. Getting the current route name and if its equal "posts" it will not show the `header-bar` component.

Something like this:

```
{{#if currentRoute != 'login'}}
    {{header-bar}}
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}
```

Any idea on could I achieve this or something similar that solves my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`applicatiion` controller has a property names `currentRouteName`. You can use it.

If you want to use in another template you need to define that in controller.

test.js (controller)

```
init(){
  this._super(...arguments);
  let appCtrl = Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('controller:application');
  this.set('appCtrl', appCtrl);
}
```

test.hbs

```
{{appCtrl.currentRouteName}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm relevantly knew to ember.js, would you kindly give me more explanation on how to use currentRouteName on handlebars template? Thanks again.

Comment: @rafaelmsantos `{{#if currentRouteName != 'login'}}
    {{header-bar}}
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}`

Comment: @rafaelmsantos Note that according to your question I suggest this answer. I mean you should use this in `application` template only. Because `currentRouteName` is in `application` controller. If you want to use in another templates, you should define that as a property in proper controller.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using that bit of code in the `application` template.

Comment: @rafaelmsantos The problem is not from `currentRouteName`. Check others. Or copy/paste your code here please

Comment: The problem from using `!=` in `if` helper @rafaelmsantos

Comment: Please take a look at `ember-truth-helpers` addon

Comment: Thank you for your time, I solved it with your tips.

Comment: In addition to @EbrahimPasbani's answer, you can create a computed property on the Application controller. It would look something like: `isLoginRoute: Ember.computed.equal('currentRouteName', 'login')` and then use it like `{{#if isLoginRoute}} ... {{else}} ... {{/if}}` where you would have to keep in mind that `login.index` or `login.loading` or `login.error` would fail this check so maybe you could even make your own computed property that does a more thorough check.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Ebrahim Pasbani.

This syntax is still usable in latest Ember version:

```
App.__container__.lookup('controller:application').currentRouteName;
```

Comment: Its private API so please don't use it.